# Как получить имя пользователя по реплаю в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть код, где пользователь может сделать рп-команду, реплая пользователя (отвечая на его сообщение), как получить информацию об этом участнике (например fitst_name)? Ещё хотелось бы реализовать получение фамилии по ID, например что бы пользователь писал "РП пожал руку @username" и бот получал фамилию с этого username (примерно так: Сергей пожал руку Влад) Код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from random import randint as ri

@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def new_message(message: types.Message):
    if 'РП' in message.text:
         args = message.text.split()
         await message.reply(message.from_user.first_name, args[1]) #тут что-то делать
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPD:

Вот наверное то, что вы хотели. Подробнее описал [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437563/479903):

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="handshake")
async def send_handshake(message: types.Message):
    your_id = message.from_id
    your_name = message.from_user.username
    try:
        friend_name = message.reply_to_message.from_user.username
        friend_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
        # await message.delete()
        await message.answer(f'[{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)}) пожал руку [{friend_name}](tg://user?id={str(friend_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
    except:
        # await message.delete()
        await message.answer(f'[{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)}) жмет руку всем', parse_mode="Markdown")
```

А это результат работы бота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я попробовал, но получаю так только свое имя, а не того, на чьё сообщение я ответил

Comment: @TFader, проверьте, добавил код, вроде это то, что вам было нужно. Ну практически то, что было нужно. Тут **пожатие** производится путем цитирования сообщения

Answer (score 1):

```
msg.from_user.first_name
```

ровно точно так же как

```
msg.from_user.id
```

и

```
msg.from_user.username
```

msg или message зависит от того, что в скробках у асинх деф

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="handshake")
async def send_handshake(***message***: types.Message):
```

Answer (score 0):

Узнать имя пользователя, на чьё сообщение мы ответили:

```
message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name
```

Увы, но на второй вопрос ответа я не нашёл

Answer (score 0):

по поводу второго вопроса. попробуйте создать бота, с хэндлером- перехватывающим нужное вам сообщение, отправте это сообщение, и print'ом посмотреть как текстово это сообщение выглядит. возможно, тг на своём системном языке сообщает чьё сообщение пересылается.