# Telebot рп команды телеграм боту

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

помогите пожалуйста хочу в бота добавить рп команды по типу **/обнять (реплай на чье то сообщение) ** бот отвечает **пользователь обнял(а) пользователь2**

я уже что только не пробовал вообще не понимаю как это реализовать

изначально пытался так но она работает на меня самого же(

````
def handler_new_member(message):
        user_name = message.from_user.first_name
        user_nametwo = message.from_user.first_name
        botik.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {user_name} обнял\n {user_nametwo}') ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для aiogram:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="обнять")
async def send_hug(message: types.Message):
    your_id = message.from_id
    your_name = message.from_user.username
    try:
        friend_name = message.reply_to_message.from_user.username
        friend_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
        # await message.delete()
        await message.answer(f'[{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)}) обнял-приподнял [{friend_name}](tg://user?id={str(friend_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
    except:
        # await message.delete()
        await message.answer(f'[{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)}) обнял-приподнял всех друзей', parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Работает так - если написать в чат **/обнять**, то бот просто напишет **<твое_имя> обнял-приподнял всех друзей**, а если нажать Ответить на чье-нибудь сообщение и написать **/обнять**, то тогда бот напишет **<твое_имя> обнял-приподнял <имя_кого_процетировал>**. Имена при этом кликабельны, при нажатии открывается профиль контакта. Если раскомменировать `await message.delete()` и у бота в группе есть права администратора, то бот будет предварительно подчищать сообщения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]